# IOexception sending an Object to a server (socket connection)

Tags: java, sockets, null, client-server, ioexception

This is a homework assignment just to clarify.

The problem is, I have a client and server connection however I am sending a class I made namely "Course", through to the server over a socket connection (TCP). This is where I am encountering a problem with an IOexception.

```
public void handleMessageFromClientUI(Object message)
  {
    try
    {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("message.ser"));

      sendToServer(out);
    }
   catch(IOException e)
   {
      clientUI.display
        ("Could not send message" + e.getCause());
    quit();
    }
  }
```

I'm sending a course object that I have serialized, but I keep getting the cause of the exception as being null.
For the purpose of simplicity and because I have a lot of other classes and code I've only put this snippet here, however I can add more if needed.
Any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

I have added sendToServer() on request

```
final public void sendToServer(Object msg) throws IOException {

        if (clientSocket == null || output == null){

            throw new SocketException("socket does not exist");}

        output.writeObject(msg);
    }
```

Further testing shows that I may have the variable output as null which is why I get the exception.

```
output = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
```

That's the initializing statement for output, very confused but I think I just moved a step forward.

Thanks.

Comment: I have tested whether the object is null by printing it, and I get an output for that.

Comment: What's inside `sendToServer` ?

Comment: Telling us you have an `IOException` without providing a stack trace is futile.

Answer (score -1):

The object message received in the handlemessagefromUIclient did not need to be serialized to be sent over the connection!

Comment: Surely you mean it *did* need to be *`Serializable`*?